# Autowired causing exceptions in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am having trouble getting the Autowired annotation to work in my spring boot application.

The error that I am receiving is "Could not autowire field. No qualifying bean of type"

I have verified that the code from the Controller on down are not POJO and have Spring annotations.

I am also unable to run my main method outside of a package. Any suggestions?

```
package com.xxx.controller;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleWebJspApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SampleWebJspApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleWebJspApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

UserService class

```
package com.xxx.service;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import com.xxx.entity.User;
    import com.xxx.repository.UserRepository;

    @Service
    public class UserService {

        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;

        public List<User> findAll() {
            return userRepository.findAll();
        }

    }
```

UserRepository class

```
package com.xxx.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.xxx.entity.User;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be two possible reasons for this:

- Package of component is not included in `@ComponentScan` packages.
- Package of repository is not included in `@EnableJPARepositories` packages.

Comment: I removed the SpringBootApplication annotation and replaced it with ComponentScan and EnableJpaRepositories. Then, I add the necessary basePackages. That didn't fix the problem. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your @SpringBootApplication annotation is in the package "com.xxx.controller", so Spring will be able to scan components from this package to packages inside it.

> [Docs:](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) If specific packages are not defined, scanning will occur from the package of the class that declares this annotation.

Try:

- Add @ComponentScan({"com.xxx"}) under @SpringBootApplication
  or modify to @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.xxx"}).

or

- Just move your class "SampleWebJspApplication" to the package "com.xxx". This is probably the best solution, once this class of yours doesn't look like a controller.